# Trying to install yfinance but it doesn't work

Tags: python

Tried to install yfinance module but I get several warning messages in my terminal. I tried to use the module in python but it told me that the module did not exist.

```
Installing collected packages: urllib3, pytz, python-dateutil, numpy, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests, pandas, multitasking, lxml, appdirs, yfinance
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.9 are installed in '/Users/hej/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script normalizer is installed in '/Users/hej/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script sample is installed in '/Users/hej/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.4 certifi-2022.9.24 charset-normalizer-2.1.1 idna-3.4 lxml-4.9.1 multitasking-0.0.11 numpy-1.23.3 pandas-1.5.0 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2022.4 requests-2.28.1 urllib3-1.26.12 yfinance-0.1.75
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
hej@Hejs-iMac ~ %
```

Comment: Looks like you are on Mac. How did you install pyhon?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/  I installed this python.